# How to run Azure Function app on a different port in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I am setting local host port in local.setting.json. Referring Microsoft doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local

The file looks like below

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""   
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7073
  }
}
```

When I run/debug the solution , VS still host the app on default port (7071)

I have checked the bin directory, the `local.setting.json` file is geting there with above settings.
Running **Azure Fucntion CLI** (`func host start`) from bin directory correctly read the port number.

Looks like VS is not using the `"LocalHttpPort`" port. Is there any other changes required in the settings. I have Visual Studio 2017 Preview (2)

Comment: In VS2017 15.9.5 using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` v1.0.26 your approach is working just fine.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

**Update**: If you're just looking to change the port, you don't have to set it through the file specified in the question. Check [Thuc Nguyen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51415335/3234163)

**Original answer:**

the command line takes precedence over the settings file, the problem is that VS passes an explicit port on the command line.

work around is to go through `project -> properties -> Debug`, then under `Application arguments` take control of the args. you can type `host start --pause-on-error`

[image]

*Edit from ravinsp:*

***Update for .Net Core 2.0 function project:***

The command line arguments you have to pass are different. You have to pass in the path to a dll in front. Like this:
`%AppData%\..\Local\Azure.Functions.V2.Cli\2.0.1-beta.22\Azure.Functions.Cli.dll host start --pause-on-error` You can see for yourself by running the function in Visual Studio and using the process explorer to see command line args to dotnet.exe process.

edit: a word

Comment: Alas this does not work with the .NET Core 2.0 version of the Functions tooling, only the .NET Framework version.

Comment: In .Net Core 2.0, you have to give the following as the command line args. I found this out via process explorer while running the function via VS.
Put this in the "Application Arguments" field: C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.V2.Cli\2.0.1-beta.22\Azure.Functions.Cli.dll host start --port 8888 --pause-on-error

Comment: With VS 2017 15.9.4 for .Net Core 2.0, I added the following json {"host":{"LocalHttpPort":7073}} near the end of my local.settings.json file. Next I created in the project/Properties/Debug a new Project Profile and set its Application arguments to: start --port 7073 --pause-on-error . Note the profile is set to "Project" not Executable. This allows me to have multiple test profiles. With this setup I can run multiple Azure Functions at the same time in debug in Visual Studio when I set the Solution Properties Configuration to Multiple.

Comment: With VS 2019, and function 2.22.0, this has changed to: %LOCALAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.22.0\cli\func.exe" host start --port 7071 --pause-on-error

Answer (score 142):

I am using the CLI version 1.2.1, and the following `Application arguments` setting in `Project Properties -> Debug` worked for me.

`host start --port 7074 --nodeDebugPort 5860`

Comment: This worked for me. Simplest solution on this page for my problem.

Comment: Should be the answer really, i specifically wanted to debug at least 2 functions at the same time and needed the best way to tell each function what port to run on

Comment: I think it's the right answer to the question in the title too. The accepted answer was addressing a particular issue the author had, but the title is a lot more generic and this answer fits better.

Comment: why is this not the accepted answer? Thanks so much! :)

Comment: I like this solution too, simplest, easy to control.

Comment: What does -nodeDebugPort denote?

Comment: For me it worked without nodeDebugPort  >                                                                 
    host start --port 7070

Answer (score 50):

Update Project Properties -> Debug to following

host start --port 7073 --pause-on-error

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that this works well with V3 functions and VS 2019.

Comment: This worked for visual studio 2022 via properties -> debug -> Open debug lunch profile UI -> Command line arguments

Answer (score 10):

As of this version:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2912 Commit hash: bfcbbe48ed6fdacdf9b309261ecc8093df3b83f2)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.14287.0
```

you only have to type `start --port 7074` in the Application Arguments box

Comment: This is the correct answer For Functions v3, Visual Studio 2019+

Answer (score 7):

> **Correct answer for .NET Core 2.0 / .NET Standard 2.0 Azure Functions project in Visual Studio 2017 when you have installed Azure Functions Core Tools 2.x Runtime via NPM**

I followed @ahmelsayed's answer and in particular, @ravinsp's comments for .net core 2.0 comments. While very helpful and putting me on the right track, they did not work for me without a crucial and non-intuitive modification so I'm adding a fresh answer.

### TL;DR;

If you've used NPM to install Azure Functions Core Tools 2.x Runtime then you may need to set Project/Properties/Debug/Application Arguments to:

```
C:\Users\<myuserid>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func.dll host start --port 8888 --pause-on-error
```

Long answer follows ...

### My Setup

During this exercise, my setup is fully up to date (at time of writing) and as follows:

- Visual Studio 2017 Professional: 15.6.2
- Azure Functions and Web Job Tools: 15.0.40215.0
- Windows 10 10.0.16299 Build 16299
- Azure Functions Core Tools (installed as per the [Develop and run Azure functions locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) document from Microsoft) reports (in Git Bash):

  `me@MYDESKTOP ~
  $ func
  <snip/>
  Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.1-beta.24)
  Function Runtime Version: 2.0.11587.0`

fwiw, the Functions App settings tab for this Functions App on Azure reads:

```
Runtime version: 2.0.11587.0 (beta)
```

### My Issue

When I run my functions project (with no application arguments) I get this in the console output:

```
[17/03/2018 21:06:38] Starting Host (HostId=MYMACHINE, Version=2.0.11353.0, ProcessId=<snip/>
Listening on http://localhost:7071/
```

This in and of itself might not be a problem, but I'm getting annoying "works on my machine, fails when publishing to azure" type issues, so I want to make sure that local execution is using same functions runtime as azure (i.e. 2.0.11587.0 which, as per the setup notes above, it is/should be, right?)

So, based on @ravinsp's instructions, I run a find on my C drive to locate Azure.Functions.Cli.dll - there's only one, and it's located at `C:\Users\<myuserid>\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.V2.Cli\2.0.1-beta\Azure.Functions.Cli.dll`  which seems very consistent with @ravinsp's answer.

So, I add the following Project/Properties/Debug/Application Arguments:

```
C:\Users\<myuserid>\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.V2.Cli\2.0.1-beta\Azure.Functions.Cli.dll host start --port 8888 --pause-on-error
```

then I DO get port 8888, but runtime weirdly is *still* being reported as 2.0.11353.

```
[17/03/2018 21:13:02] Starting Host (HostId=MYMACHINE, Version=2.0.11353.0, ProcessId=<snip/>
Listening on http://localhost:8888/
```

### Solution

Given that running func from Git Bash as per the above showed runtime of 2.0.11587.0, I tried `which func` which returned `/c/Users/<myuserid>/AppData/Roaming/npm/func`
.  I did a cat on it and long story short I could see that ultimately it was running `C:\Users\<myuserid>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func.exe`, and that in that same directory there was a `func.dll`.

So, I tried the following Project/Properties/Debug/Application Arguments:

```
C:\Users\<myuserid>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func.dll host start --port 8888 --pause-on-error
```

then finally I do get ...

```
[17/03/2018 21:16:29] Starting Host (HostId=MYMACHINE, Version=2.0.11587.0, ProcessId=<snip/>
Listening on http://localhost:8888/
```

and, crucially, the error I was getting when publishing to Azure starts manifesting itself locally too.

Ok, now the runtimes all in sync, time to get down to fixing my actual bug :)

Answer (score 7):

To do this

Select the **`Function App Project in Visual Studio -> Hit Alt+Enter`** and navigate to Debug settings and set

```
host start --port 8085 --nodeDebugPort 6890
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Visual Studio 2022 and Function v4, you could set the port in the `launchSettings.json` file:
[image]

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "<functionapp project name>": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--port 7137",
      "launchBrowser": false
    }
  }
}
```

This setting can also be updated through UI:
`Properties > Debug > General > Open debug launch profiles UI`:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I used the accepted answer but I still got an error when the debugger port was trying to bind because both function apps were trying to bind to 5858.

To get around that I added one more attribute to the application arguments in the project settings and my arguments look like this:

```
host start --pause-on-error --nodeDebugPort 5860
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the way I use a different port in local.settings.json file, while running this in Intellij. You can use any other IDE as well, local.settings.json works everywhere.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7072
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Visual Studio for MacOS right click on your project, click Options, click on `Run -> Configurations -> Default` and enter `host start --port 7073 --pause-on-error` in the Arguments field.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following in the "Command line arguments" in VS 2022 and .Net 6 works:
start --port 7074

Comment: Please add documentation link & implementation detail here.