# Debugging two Azure Functions projects locally

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I have two Azure Functions projects.

I have one project, A, running on `localhost:7071/api/....`

[image: console output of project A, showing port 7071]

I have changed the other project, B, to run on `localhost:8888/api/...`

[image: console output of project B, showing port 8888]

I am calling a function which is running on project A from a function in Project B! How can I debug two Azure Functions projects locally? I cannot find any docs to help me.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead, copy & paste the text into the question directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the issue add the command line switch `--nodeDebugPort 5859` to your launching of `func host` to set the port for one of the sessions.

If you are launching from within Visual Studio you need to go to `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Debug`, then under `Application arguments` you need to pass in a value that looks similar to `host start --pause-on-error --nodeDebugPort 5859` (again, for one project).

See [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/310) and [this video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44977350/1171619).

Comment: -pause-on-error in v3 throws an error, Application arguments only needs to be the following "host start -p <portNumber>