# Azure Functions in Cloud on Specific Port on Consumption Plan?

Tags: azure-functions

What is the correct way to have a runtime Function listen on one particular inbound port?

Looking to force a .NET 7 Isolated Function running under Windows in Consumption Plan to only listen on a single dedicated port. Shifting through web searches, Found the App Config setting of `WEBSITES_PORT` but that doesn't seem to be correct.

Is a "Premium" App Service Plan required to do this?

EDIT: Clarification: as I put in the title, this is not about debugging, this is about the Function executing at runtime in the Consumption Plan/Tier. I am aware of the local debugging port configuration. I want, in Azure, for FunctionA to run on port 8090 and FunctionB to run on port 8091 using the same App Service Plan on the back-end. I am aware of the scalability constraints in doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: It is only possible to change the Port of Azure Function locally to make the Azure Function Trigger listen to different Local Port. 
Refer this **[SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976890/how-to-run-azure-function-app-on-a-different-port-in-visual-studio)** by Thomas and Vipin

Comment: Edit your **`local.settings.json`** file to listen **to your desired local port**:-

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7072
  }
}
```

Comment: Debug settings in visual studio -https://i.imgur.com/woFSvRi.png

Comment: Function ran on port 7072 locally - https://i.imgur.com/1pIKHi1.png

Comment: According to this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2022#remote-debugger-ports-on-microsoft-azure-app-service) by Default Azure App service listens to Port 4024 and when ***I visited Kudu tool and checked the Remote, Server and Remote Debugging port it is set by default***, Refer below:-

![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/LLYBhgT.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to change the Port of Azure Function locally to make the Azure Function Trigger listen to different Local Port.

Refer this **[SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976890/how-to-run-azure-function-app-on-a-different-port-in-visual-studio)** by Thomas and Vipin

Edit your **`local.settings.json`** file to listen **to your desired local port**:-

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7072
  }
}
```

[image]

Now, When I ran my Function locally it listened to the 7072 port like below:-

[image]

According to this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2022#remote-debugger-ports-on-microsoft-azure-app-service) by Default Azure App service listens to Port 4024 and when ***I visited Kudu tool and checked the Remote, Server and Remote Debugging port it is set by default***, Refer below:-

[image]