# Can I override Azurite ports when launching automatically from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, azurite

When I run Azurite with a Visual Studio 2022 Functions Project, it has a port conflict with an IT Security agent that my company runs on our systems.  I need to override the ports.  I see that this can be done easily with command line options, but is there a way to set the command line options when running automatically within Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1):

**`The only way you can add Load different Functions in different ports is by adding the port settings in > Select Function App Project Solution > right click > Properties > Debug > Open Debug launch profiles ui > Add --port 7500 for one Function App project, Open second project in another VS Studio and add --port 7010 for the second Function`**:-

[image]

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

Reference [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976890/how-to-run-azure-function-app-on-a-different-port-in-visual-studio)

Apart from this there's no other option to run your Function app in different ports apart from running it manually from **command line terminal/command prompt** with the command below:-

```
func host start --port 7300
```

***Output:-***

[image]

Comment: That will not affect what port the Azurite emulator runs on, but only the local Function app.